# Difference between originator of transaction and owner of the source fund

Tags: transactions

Here is an excerpt from Andreas Antonopoulos, Mastering Bitcoin, Chapter 5 (Transaction), sub chapter(Creating Transactions):

[image]

My question is what's the difference between the originator of transaction and owner of the source fund? 
Who actually signed the transaction? For example, if Alice pay to Bob 0.1BTC, is that transaction signed by Alice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if Alice pay to Bob 0.1BTC, is that transaction signed by Alice?

Yes.

If I understand your quotation correctly, Andreas Antonopoulos is saying that Alice's personal assistant Charlie, could have prepared the transaction without any signature and passed it to Alice for approval and signing.

I don't know which wallets support this kind of arrangement. For most of us the preparation and signing are all handled together at the same time.